# RESTFB : How to post message on friends wall using java program

Tags: java, facebook, restfb

I have facebook username of my friend. I want to post something their wall using restFB API. I am able to post on my wall. but how I have to get user_id by username.

String user_id = "1234567567"

---

```
FacebookType publishMessageResponse = facebookClient.publish("{user_id}/feed", FacebookType.class, Parameter.with("message", "RestFB 1234 "));
```

here what should be the `user_id(always numeric)`. or we can pass username also.

### ERROR

```
Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. (code 190, subcode 467) 
com.restfb.exception.FacebookOAuthException: Received Facebook error response of type OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. (code 190, subcode 467)
```

Comment: You can not post to other people’s walls via API, that was removed ages ago because it created too much spam.

Comment: is there any way to post on friends wall using facebook API like graph API and facebook4j API

Comment: As _already said_ ... No. You can let the user share something to a friend’s timeline using the Share Dialog, but that requires user interaction.